# Support multiple login at the same time in OpenFire server

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire

I've configured OpenFire for using as server for my customers.

But in following case, OpenFire doesn't give proper response:

**Customer A** login from two chat client connected to my server and chat with another **Customer B**.
The problem is that, last active **Customer A** can only get Message from **Customer B** instead of getting message in both the chat client.

Anyone have configured the OpenFire can suggest me the settings need to be changed.

Thanks.

Comment: Nice Question I also faced this issue but as my requirement I don't need it.........

Comment: @CapDroid : As suggested in documentation we can give different raster   name to identify each chat client, But the problem is that **Customer B** have two entries in online chat list with different chat raster name.

Comment: may be need to do some configure on OpenFire but I dont know about it bcz I never checked openfire server I just used only at client side ..

Comment: I would change the title a bit. I doesn't really state your problem and is a somehow misleading (multiple logins are supported by Openfire/XMPP).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is by design of XMPP, as can be seen in [RFC3921](http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html), section 11.1 "Inbound Stanzas".

To send messages addressed to a bare JID in openfire to all related full JIDs (resources + bare JID), you need to set the system property `route.all-resources` with the value `true` in Openfire (Admin Console > Server Manager > System Properties). You will have to create this system property. Also you would have to set the same priority in both clients.

See also [these](https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/route-all-resources-sending-same-message-several-times/56821?u=flow) [igniterealtime forums](https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/make-openfire-to-send-messages-to-all-active-xmpp-clients-under-same-account/56786?u=flow) [posts](https://discourse.igniterealtime.org/t/feature-request-send-message-to-all-resources/75532?u=flow).